# Textfield disabled voiceover

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

Voice Over keeps saying "Double Tap to Edit" even when the textField is disabled. Is there a way to change that? Is that set as an accessibilityHint that I can change manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a hint.  This is coming from the Accessibility Frameworks themselves.  I believe it is most likely coming from VoiceOver, calculating that the box is an Editable text field.  What you should do is set the `UIAccessibilityTraitNotEnabled` to on.  Then it will at least also be announced as dimmed.  If, with this trait enabled, you still hear the "Double tap to edit" announcement you should also post a bug on the Apple Developer site.  I would check myself, but I left my mac laptop at work, and only have my windows machine available :(.

Answer (score 0):

When I create a UITextField with the Interface Builder, VoiceOver reads out *"text field, double tap to edit"*.
However, I can't reproduce the behavior you describe according to the following operations with Interface Builder :

- Untick `User Ineraction Enabled` : VoiceOVer reads out *"dimmed - text field"*.
- Untick `Accessibility Enabled` : VoiceOver doesn't focus the UITextField at all.

I also programmatically disabled the UITextField as follows :

```
yourTextFieldOutlet.isAccessibilityElement = false
```

...and VoiceOver doesn't focus the UITextField either.

Unless I misunderstood the expression *"disable the text field"* (not an accessible element anymore), I suggest to untick `Accessibility Enabled` in the Interface Builder or to copy the snippet hereabove to **make your UITextField invisible to VoiceOver**.

Now, if you want to **prevent from fulfilling your UITextField that must be still interpreted by VoiceOVer**, untick `User Ineraction Enabled` or change programmatically its trait to `UIAccessibilityTraitNotEnabled` as ChrisCM suggested.